# WP2Static cURL error: Could not resolve host: statics.mydomain.com

Tags: wordpress, debian, multisite, static-site

I have a problem, with the plugin `WP2Static` in wordpress, when generating  statics files, the folder is created well but not the files.

Export log:

> cURL error: Could not resolve host: statics.mydomain.com

I'm using a VPS with Debian 9.
wordpress version: 5.2.1
WP2Static version: 6.6.5
I use Docker to generate my wordpress.
PS: The domain name used does not exist (statics.mydomain.com), I add it to the hosts file.

Target Directory:

```
/var/www/html/statics/site1
```

I installed the project on a VirtualBox and the plugin works fine. The problem must come from the DNS but I can not find the solution!

Have you ever had this problem ? Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is as you suspect a DNS resolution issue.

When you add the entry to your hosts file, I presume this is on your host.

The docker container running your application also needs to know where `statics.mydomain.com` resolves to.

Add an entry to the hosts file within your container running WordPress. You can then test by running cURL on CLI within that container.

WP2Static uses WordPress's knowledge of the Site URL and Home URLs from its Settings area. Ensure that these are also set to `statics.mydomain.com` and not overridden via `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem by adding the dns to the hosts file of the container! Thank you!!